# Bevel modifier not working on SVG converted to mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm running Blender Version 2.83.0 (2.83.0 2020-06-03) on mac 10.15.5.

I've been tinkering with modeling items and I can't make mesh modifier operations work for me.

- I draw a path in Adobe Illustrator
- It looks like like the outline of seahorse.
- Export to SVG.
- Go blender.
- Import SVG
- convert to mesh
- extrude
- Boolean two cylinders

The last item want to do is break the edge with a bevel. It won't bevel.

I've also tried to use the geometry tab to extrude the SVG curve and bevel it there before converting to mesh. However then it won't let me boolean the cylinders out.

Any direction would be appreciated.

[image: model mesh]

Answer (score 5):

Curve objects get really bad topology when converted to mesh. Boolean operations will also contribute to make the topology even worse.
And at the end the irregular and triangulated topology of the object will not let you bevel.

So keep the object as a curve.

Create the object, with the holes, in illustrator as a path (no need to use booleans).

[image]

Import the SVG into blender, do not convert to mesh.

[image]

To do the extrusion as curve make it a **2D curve**, set the **fill** to mode  to "**both**".

[image]

In the **Geometry** controls set the **extrusion** level and the **bevel**  as well.

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you. I'll try this in the morning.

Comment: I'm new to posting here. Is it common to have posts censored and edited by someone other than the original poster?

Comment: @mbrando Any user can edit questions and answers. Take the [tour] to understand how the site works.

Comment: Thanks. I took the tour. I see the editing part.

Comment: @mbrando questions about blender don't need an emotional context to be clear. But if you feel it that the original text helps others understand the question. you can always roll back the edits.

Comment: that is fine. I just had not run into this before where someone else picked apart my post. I was only trying to give perspective.