# How to improve boolean modifier on SVG logo

Tags: modifiers

Rookie asking again.

I imported .SVG logo into blender to make it 3D. My idea was extrude different components and then drill the hole by boolean modifier.

Obviously I must be missing something as the boolean draw only edges into other object, but did not make holes. Let see if you could see the issue from the following picture:

[image]

The edges I have selected are from bottom. Inside of those selection you can see the edges coming from boolean modifier. The same is on roof (not selected edges).

Total different question is, why there were few vertexes outside of the object. There were not many <10. The edges to the vertexes are those few going down.

Is there something I could change on this? At first I though this was because I forgot to fill all caps, but that (alt + f) did not solved the issue.

...or is there total different and better way of doing this.

Comment: Curves converted to meshes yield bad topology most of the time. On top of that booleans will create new problems. Try to create the logo with all of it's holes and detail in whatever vector drawing program you are using (inkscape, illustrator or so). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184543/bevel-modifier-not-working-on-mesh/184547#184547

Comment: Also, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Thank you @susu, that link was very good! I have always thought that boolean is my friend and that will solve all my problems. But I really did not though in a way to finalize the shape on Inkscape.

Comment: Booleans are treacherous friends, beware of them. They can be wonderful in just a few situations, but mostly you want to stay away from them.